# How do I block traffic to "evaluated" IPs without using a separate DNS?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, blocking

To test the 'truthfulness' of a network function, I have set up a virtual machine running windows 10. I'm running the Microsoft network monitor on the virtual machine, and on the next level up, I'm comparing the network requests of the virtual box to the network requests that the virtual box claims that it made.

Note that the virtual box has no network requests until I start a VM.

My current method of trying to block these  network requests is to use the hosts file for any domains, and the firewall for any IPs. The Firewall has been working fine so far, It's the hosts file that's giving me a headache.

There seem to be certain "Evaluated" domains that the hosts file will not block, and I need them blocked

for example, here are some domains that you cannot block with the hosts file:

```
dm3p.wns.notify.windows.com.akadns.net
e1553.dspg.akamaiedge.net
e15275.g.akamaiedge.net
cs9.wac.phicdn.net
arc.msn.com.nsatc.net
```

How do I block requests to and from these addresses using only vanilla windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are websites for Microsoft telemetry, Windows Update and Akamai network
optimizations.

Analyzing the websites in your list:

- `dm3p.wns.notify.windows.com.akadns.net` is `13.89.217.116` registered by Microsoft.
  `cs9.wac.phicdn.net` is the same for Verizon users.
  They are probably used principally for Windows Update.
- `arc.msn.com.nsatc.net` is probably used by Windows Spotlight for
  new lock screen images and suggested apps.
  It can be turned off with no negative effects as
  [described by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/manage-connections-from-windows-operating-system-components-to-microsoft-services#bkmk-spotlight).
- `e1553.dspg.akamaiedge.net` is `104.121.28.119` registered by Akamai
  to figure out what's the closest server to you to speed things up.
  `e15275.g.akamaiedge.net` is the same.

The results of disabling them might be incorrect Windows Update patches
applied to your computer, and slower Internet access on the Akamai network.

**Recommendations**

I would recommend, rather than blocking the Microsoft websites,
to turn them off by disabling their services for the ones that are
judged unnecessary.
This is done in:

- *Settings > Privacy* allows nowadays to turn off most of the telemetry options
- The Microsoft article
  [Manage connections from Windows operating system components to Microsoft services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/manage-connections-from-windows-operating-system-components-to-microsoft-services)
  contains instruction on turning off dozens of Windows services.

I would recommend leaving the Akamai sites to do their job.
You may block them at the router by IP address, but you are only degrading
your Internet experience.

**Blocking**

Windows UPdate can be disabled from *Administrative Tools > Services*.

For good measures, the Microsoft Store can be disabled via regedit,
key `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsStore`,
right-click and select *New > DWORD 32-bit*, named `RemoveWindowsStore`
with the value of `1`.

As Windows will not block these IP addresses, you may try 
installing a third-party firewall, from which these websites will not
get a special treatment, so might succeed in blocking them.
Disable in that case the Windows Defender firewall.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I'm 100% sure I want no connection to these sites. I need to block the connection.

Comment: As stated above, you may do that by: (1) Closing all telemetry services, (2) Using the router's firewall.

Comment: The firewall is already blocking the IPS for above addresses, and I've used [dw10S](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/destroy_windows_10_spying.html) to shut off telemetry

Comment: You may also block them by installing a third-party firewall that doesn't treat these websites differently from other websites.

Answer (score 2):

We can try this link which talked about Block or Redirect specific Websites in windows hosts file.
[https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/edit-windows-hosts-file-to-block-redirect-websites/][1]

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1

Ping the domains which you want to block to get their IP addresses, and then follow these [steps](https://malwaretips.com/threads/how-to-block-websites-in-windows-firewall-guide.55305/):

> 1. Open Windows Firewall from the Control Panel;
> 2. Select Advanced Settings;
>
> On windows 10 just search for Windows Firewall in the search bar and choose Windows Firewall with Advanced Settings
>
> 3. Select Inbound Rules from the left panel. Select New Rule from the right side (Action window);
> 4. Select Custom (Custom rule) and click Next;
> 5. All Programs should be selected and click Next;
> 6. Click next on the Protocols and Ports page (leave as it is);
> 7. In the scope page enter the IP (i.e. 192.168.1.1 but not www) address of the site you want to block in the "Which remote IP addresses does this rule apply to?" section;
> 8. Select Block the connection on the Action page, click Next;
> 9. Leave all boxes checked on Profile page if you don't ever want to see the website on any network connection, modify if you want to allow on a Domain, Public or Private Network;
> 10. Enter a name for the new rule you created and click Finish;

*However, this will stop working if IPs associated with the domain change, in which case, do the following:*

## Method 2

Download one of the [several 3rd party](https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-firewall) free firewalls available for Windows (such as [this](https://www.zonealarm.com/software/free-firewall/?AID=11556579&PID=6361382&SID=trd-1361536769810561460&network=cj) one), and add the domains to the blocking list.

Comment: Method 1: The problem asked here is that it doesn't work for these IPs. Method 2: Already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to block them inside of Windows you would be better off blocking them upstream at a hardware firewall and DNS server. The external firewall can't be modified by the OS on the fly like the internal firewall can. Likewise, you can shut down any host using a DNS black hole like https://pi-hole.net/ where the idea is the same. The OS can't modify or go around the external DNS server like it can with it's own hosts file.